# How to highlight the audio playing words in Amazon Polly

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, speech-to-text, amazon-polly

I'm trying to implement amazon Polly in an application. It is an MVC application.
I
was able to retrieve the audio from the text and it works fine. And am trying to highlight the respective text in the webpage while playing that audio. like the rear speaker does.
My aim is to implement it without a third-party application. I went through the documentation but I can't find anything useful. I didn't find any options that automatically highlight the text in amazon Polly itself.

Can we do anything with Speech marks for this? is there any way to do this?

Thanks in Advance :)

**Edit**

I have the speech mark JSON result. Now am stuck on how to sync this result with an HTML audio tag.

```
{"time":6,"type":"word","start":0,"end":2,"value":"Hi"}
{"time":587,"type":"word","start":4,"end":6,"value":"my"}
{"time":754,"type":"word","start":7,"end":11,"value":"name"}
{"time":1147,"type":"word","start":12,"end":14,"value":"is"}
{"time":1305,"type":"word","start":15,"end":19,"value":"John"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have the speech mark JSON result. Now am stuck on how to sync this result with an HTML audio tag.

You can use the [`timeupdate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event) event on and [`audio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) element and sync the [`audio.currentTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime) property with the best matching [speech mark from Polly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/using-speechmarks.html).

This assumes that `audio` references the JavaScript variable for the HTML audio element who has it's `src` set to the audio file returned from Polly that corresponds to the text's speech marks:

```js
function getSpeechMarkAtTime(speechMarks, time) {
  const length = speechMarks.length
  let match = speechMarks[0]
  let found = false
  let i = 1

  while (i < length && !found) {
    if (speechMarks[i].time <= time) {
      match = speechMarks[i]
    } else {
      found = true
    }

    i++
  }

  return match
}

function onTimeUpdate(speechMark) {
  /**
   * Update your HTML and CSS based on the attributes
   * of the speech mark at the audio's current time.
   */
}

audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => {
  // Polly Speech Marks use milliseconds
  const currentTime = audio.currentTime * 1000
  const speechMark = getSpeechMarkAtTime(speechMarksJSONResult, currentTime)

  // Some custom callback
  onTimeUpdate(speechMark)
})
```

Comment: @AmalPs if it works for you do you mind marking it as accepted?

Comment: I haven't tried yet. Seems good and looks like would work

Comment: It does as I used this implementation recently at work. Only caveat is that the `timeupdate` event frequency is dependent upon system load so at times small (one syllable) words may not get highlighted. The `SpeechSynthesis` and `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` API with the `boundary` event work much better.

The only remaining part is how you update your HTML/CSS. I was using React, but I'm not sure what your HTML or CSS looks like. Thanks.

Comment: Yes I noticed that, the time interval has some issues while syncing, but the solution seems  good. I am using MVC so implemented this using JQuery with my own custom methods. I was able to sync 95% but have some other issues with the html tags like &nbsp. But your solution will work. Hope it will help others in future :)